# how to call a async function inside setTimeout

Tags: node.js

We have one ASYNC FUNCTION which does screenshot capture.
Our need is now to call this ASYNC FUNCTION five times in the interval of 15 seconds. we have tried SetTimeout, and SetInterval and all delays wait in node.js.
We are not able to call our ASYNC FUNCTION inside this SetTimeouts.
Help us as we are new to node.js.

```
class QnABot extends ActivityHandler{
constructor(logger) {
        super();
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {                            
              let counter = 0;
              let timer = setInterval(function() {
              console.log('I am an asynchronous message');
              await this.uploadcaptureattachment(context); 
              counter += 1;
              if (counter >= 5) {
                  clearInterval(timer);
              }
            }, 5000);
         });

  }

async uploadcaptureattachment(turnContext) { 
         var screencapture = require('screencapture')
         screencapture(function (err, imagePath) {
      })
        screencapture('D:/output.png', function (err, imagePath) {
      })
  }
}
```

ERROR :
await this.uploadcaptureattachment(context);
^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `async` to your function:

```
setInterval(async function() {
    console.log('I am an asynchronous message');
    await this.uploadcaptureattachment(context); // WE ARE CALLING OUR ASYNC FUNCTION HERE
    counter += 1;
    if (counter >= 5) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcos Luis: i added async in setInterval but now i am getting error like UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.uploadcaptureattachment is not a function

Comment: From what I can see in your code `uploadcaptureattachment` is outside your class, so you would have to call it like: `await uploadcaptureattachment(context);`

Comment: When i remove 'this' its giving error like UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: uploadcaptureattachment is not defined

Comment: setInterval(async () => { await this.uploadcaptureattachment(context) },3000);  this is working.

Comment: You should edit your question code then, cause there are functions misplaced